# Check that $\eta^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}=0$

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace

I'm trying to solve a problem and I have some problems for that. The problem is to show that $\eta^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}=0$, where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkoswki metric: diag(1,-1,-1,-1), and $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the improved energy-momentum tensor of a massless scalar field, given by the following expression:

\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{3}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi-\frac{1}{6}\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho\phi\partial^\rho\phi-\frac{1}{3}\phi\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\phi
\end{equation}

raising indices and knowing that $\eta^{{\mu\nu}}\eta_{\mu\nu}=\mathbb{I_4}$ I obtain,

\begin{equation}
\eta^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{3}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac{1}{6}\partial_\rho\phi\partial^\rho\phi-\frac{1}{3}\phi\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi
\end{equation}

taking into account that I'm working with a massless scalar field I have suppossed that the lagrangian density is nothing other than
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^\mu\phi
\end{equation}
for this lagrangian density we have that the equation of motion is
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial\left(\partial_\mu\phi\right)}\right)=\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi=0
\end{equation}
so the final term in the expresion of $\eta^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$ vanishes. With this I finally conclude that,

\begin{equation}
\eta^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{3}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac{1}{6}\partial_\rho\phi\partial^\rho\phi
\end{equation}
but I don't see that this expresion is zero :(. I don't know if my steps are wrong so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}\neq\Bbb I_4$

Comment: $\eta^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\mu\nu} =\delta^\nu_{\nu} = 4$. Then the trace of the energy-momentum tensor is indeed 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is that $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu} \neq \mathbb I_4$.  In general one has that $\eta^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\rho \nu} = \delta^\mu_\rho$, so setting $\mu=\rho$ and summing simply yields the trace of the $\delta$ tensor.  This is clearly just the dimension of the spacetime under consideration, so in this case that's 3+1=4.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much!